# kafka remove connection from group

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I using kafka and spring boot application for  consuming message
after read some message from topic I will receive this error

> [2020-07-07 17:05:32,265] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Member consumer-1-708fe639-905d-432a-b6ba-17bf58adcf03 in group biker-service-prod has left, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
> [2020-07-07 17:05:32,267] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Preparing to rebalance group biker-service-prod in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 460 (__consumer_offsets-7) (reason: removing member consumer-1-708fe639-905d-432a-b6ba-17bf58adcf03 on LeaveGroup) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
> [2020-07-07 17:05:32,267] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Group biker-service-prod with generation 461 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-7) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

this is my config in consumer side

> spring.kafka.listener.poll-timeout=3000000

> spring.kafka.consumer.heartbeat-interval=500

> spring.kafka.consumer.fetch-max-wait=3000000

> spring.kafka.consumer.auto-commit-interval=1000

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **broker has decided your consumer is dead**, as it didn't call `poll()` within the needed interval.

Take a look for these [consumer-side](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html) params:

- `max.poll.interval.ms`
- `session.timeout.ms`

These will decide when your consumer will be considered dead and throw the exception you are showing. Take care of the time you need processing a message, if it is bigger than the defined `max.poll.interval.ms`, you should:

1. Decrease the time needed to process the msg and call `poll()` again.

or

2. Increase the `max.poll.interval.ms` and `session.timeout.ms` intervals.

Comment: and/or decrease `max.poll.records`.

Comment: agreed, if you loop over the received iterator. Anyway, I always believed not looping through it (just calling next()) and then calling poll() again was a better idea, as poll() is just going to do nothing if the consumer already owns unprocessed messages, and, at the same time, avoiding consumer timeouts and following rebalances. Good point, anyway

Comment: spring.kafka.listener.poll-timeout=3000000
spring.kafka.consumer.heartbeat-interval=500
spring.kafka.consumer.fetch-max-wait=3000000
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-commit-interval=1000

i set this config in consumer side 
is there wrong config?

Comment: try setting the poll timeout to a higher value. but, anyway, take a look why your consumer takes as much to loop again and process the next message, that may be the key here